# OPENROWSET for Oracle

Tags: oracle

Could anybody help me *translate* this query from T-SQL to PLSQL, please?

I am using SQL Developer.

`UPDATE schema.Table SET PICTURES =(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '\\shared folder\Picture.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) a) WHERE (personID = 1111)`

Thank you!

Comment: Please, describe what function is an issue and what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to apply a single image to a single person table row by selecting from an image file external to the database.

If my understanding is correct then I suggest you investigate Oracle **EXTERNAL TABLE**, **DIRECTORY** object and **DBMS_LOB** package.

Using some variant of these will certainly provide the solution you need.

Comment: The thing is I need to insert images into a BLOB column on the database where the .jpg file on a folder on Window matches the ID column on the table.
I only have SQL Developer installed on the server to do so. 
It's supposed to be an archive environment, so no application interface. I do not know how to do that in Oracle. I found something similar to what I need on the Oracle documentation, but I just need the sp or function.
[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28845/ch7.htm)

Comment: If you look at the 3 Oracle technologies I have told you about above you will be able to create exactly what you need. (You need to write your own code to achieve what you need as working outside the database is specific to your environment - you will however be able to search for examples of application of each of the above technologies and morph them to fit your use-case.)